# adding hashmap passed through bundle in viewpager fragment

Tags: android

I am using view-pager with fragment and pass hash-map through bundle instance to fragment. But it does not show all images in view-pager , only 3rd image show by default.
I am stuck on this... Any help will be appreciable.
Below is my java code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ViewPager viewPager;
    List<Fragment> fragments1;
    public MyPagerAdapter adapter1;

    static final ArrayList<HashMap<String, Integer>> list = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager1);
        fragments1 = getFragments1();
        adapter1 = new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments1);
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter1);

    }


    public class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private List<Fragment> fragments;
        public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<Fragment> fragments) {
            super(fm);
            this.fragments = fragments;
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return this.fragments.get(position);
        }
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return this.fragments.size();
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemPosition (Object object)
        {
            if (object instanceof MyImageSlider ) {
                return POSITION_NONE;
            }
            return POSITION_UNCHANGED;
        }

   }

    private List<Fragment> getFragments1() {
        List<Fragment> fList = new ArrayList<>();

        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
            HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
            map.put("0",R.drawable.first);
            map.put("1",R.drawable.second);
            map.put("2",R.drawable.three);
            map.put("3",R.drawable.four);
            map.put("4",R.drawable.xiaomi);
            list.add(map);
            fList.add(MyImageSlider.newInstance(list.get(i)));
        }

       return fList;

    }

    public static class MyImageSlider extends Fragment {
        HashMap<String, Integer> imageid;
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, Integer>> listArray = new ArrayList<>();

        public static MyImageSlider newInstance(HashMap<String, Integer> id)
        {


            MyImageSlider slider=new MyImageSlider();
            Bundle b=new Bundle();
            b.putSerializable("imageid", id);
            slider.setArguments(b);
            return slider;
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            imageid=(HashMap<String, Integer>) getArguments().getSerializable("imageid");
            listArray.add(imageid);
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.content_main, container, false);

            ImageView iv=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.img);

           for (String key : imageid.keySet()) {

               iv.setImageResource(imageid.get(key);
            }  


            return view;
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: Do you mean only third image is shown and other four images are set blank ?

Comment: no i mean it shows 3rd image repeatedly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why are you creating List of Fragment, you can create a single Fragment which is holding imageView  and pass List of images through adapter and show image on that Fragment.

Please check below code -
and let me know if you have any concern.

// This is your MainActivity.java

```
package com.sample.stack;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ViewPager viewPager;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager1);
        HashMap<String,Integer> sliderDataList = new HashMap<String,Integer>();

        sliderDataList.put("0",R.drawable.tc);
        sliderDataList.put("1",R.drawable.tc);
        sliderDataList.put("2",R.drawable.tc);
        sliderDataList.put("3",R.drawable.tc);
        sliderDataList.put("4",R.drawable.tc);
        PagerAdapter adapter1 = new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), sliderDataList, MainActivity.this);
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter1);

    }
}
```

// This is your FragmentPagerAdapter

```
package com.sample.stack;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;

import java.util.HashMap;

/**
 * Created by on 06-12-2016.
 */

public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private final HashMap<String, Integer> hMap;
    private final Context context;

    public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, HashMap<String,Integer> hMap, Context context) {
        super(fm);
        this.hMap=hMap;
        this.context=context;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return new SliderFragment(hMap,context,position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return hMap.size();
    }
}
```

// This is your Fragent containg ImageView

```
package com.sample.stack;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

/**
 * Created by Syscraft on 06-12-2016.
 */

@SuppressLint("ValidFragment")
public class SliderFragment extends Fragment {

    private final HashMap<String, Integer> urls;
    private int imageResourceId;

    private Context ctx;

    public SliderFragment(HashMap<String,Integer> urls, Context c,
                          int pos) {
        this.urls = urls;
        this.imageResourceId = pos;
        this.ctx = c;

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.slider_adapter, container, false);
        final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.sliderImages);
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);

       imageView.setImageResource(urls.get(imageResourceId+""));

        imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });

        return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: I agree with you i can exactly what you do in code but my further requirement is comparing two view-pager images . And i want to do this by comparing keys of images.

Comment: if You want to use HashMap, than you can pass  Hashmap instead of Array List

Comment: replacing Array List with Hash Map gives null pointer exception.

Comment: why it is giving null pointer exception can you please tell me ?

Comment: yes i will update my answer with Hash Map implementation

Comment: I have update my answer, pls check and let me know if have any problem

Comment: can you tell me how to remove and add values from this hashmap , because any changes in this gives me null pointer exception.

Comment: imageView.setImageResource(urls.get(imageResourceId+""));   please tell me why its again give me null pointer exception if i remove blank space from get(imageResourceId)

Comment: imageResourceId is a integer Type and we are storing String Type of Hashmap key. that why we are concate integer and String, and its result is String Type Key.

Comment: you can hMap.put() to add  value in hash map and call hMap.remove(key) for remove.

Comment: i use these methods but these gives me null pointer exception. if i remove last key then it work fine

Answer (score 0):

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
ViewPager viewPager;
```

public PagerAdapter adapter1;

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager1);
    final HashMap<String,Integer> sliderDataList = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
    sliderDataList.put("0",R.drawable.first);
    sliderDataList.put("1",R.drawable.second);
    sliderDataList.put("2",R.drawable.three);
    sliderDataList.put("3",R.drawable.four);
    sliderDataList.put("4",R.drawable.xiaomi);
     adapter1 = new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), sliderDataList, MainActivity.this);
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter1);

  //  sliderDataList.remove("3");

    adapter1.notifyDataSetChanged();
    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
          remove("3");

        }
        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });
}

public void remove(String s){
    adapter1.remove(s);
}

public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private final HashMap<String, Integer> hMap;
    private final Context context;

    public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, HashMap<String,Integer> hMap, Context context) {
        super(fm);
        this.hMap=hMap;
        this.context=context;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return new SliderFragment(hMap,context,position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return hMap.size();
    }

    public void remove(String s){
        Iterator<Map.Entry<String,Integer>> iter = hMap.entrySet().iterator();
        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry<String,Integer> entry = iter.next();
            if(s.equalsIgnoreCase(entry.getKey())){
                iter.remove();
            }
        }
        hMap.remove(s);
        adapter1.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}

@SuppressLint("ValidFragment")
public static class SliderFragment extends Fragment {

    private final HashMap<String, Integer> urls;
    private int imageResourceId;
    private Context ctx;

    public SliderFragment(HashMap<String,Integer> urls, Context c, int pos) {
        this.urls = urls;
        this.imageResourceId = pos;
        this.ctx = c;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.content_main, container, false);
        final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.img);
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
        imageView.setImageResource(urls.get(imageResourceId +""));
        return view;
    }
}
```

}